Quarto dashboard duplicate chart
I'm creating a simple dashboard with Quarto in Python. When I insert a chart with plotly like the example below, the chart gets duplicated, probably due to fig.update_layout and fig.update_traces.
I’ve tried various solutions suggested by ChatGPT, but none of them fixed the issue. Has anyone else encountered this problem and maybe found a solution?
{python}
#| title: Mediana 2019

fig1 = px.bar(
    df.sort_values(by='reddito_mediano_2019'),
    x='comune',
    y='reddito_mediano_2019',
    labels={'comune': 'Comune', 'reddito_mediano_2019': 'Reddito mediano 2019'},
    color_discrete_sequence=['#C00000']
)

fig1.update_layout(
    xaxis_title='Comune',
    yaxis_title='Reddito (€)',
    xaxis=dict(showticklabels=False),
    yaxis=dict(tickformat=",.0f"),
    template='simple_white',
    height=400,
    width=1200
)

fig1.update_traces(
    hovertemplate='<b>%{x}</b><br>' + 'Reddito mediano: €%{y:,.0f}'
)


Welcome to SO. Your code works fine for me. Also, always post sample data when you ask a question like this, it helps people debugging.

I've never worked with quarto but I've seen similar duplications in the past in other settings. Try adding fig1 =  before the updates
fig1 = px.bar(
    df.sort_values(by='reddito_mediano_2019'),
    x='comune',
    y='reddito_mediano_2019',
    labels={'comune': 'Comune', 'reddito_mediano_2019': 'Reddito mediano 2019'},
    color_discrete_sequence=['#C00000']
)

fig1 = fig1.update_layout(
    xaxis_title='Comune',
    yaxis_title='Reddito (€)',
    xaxis=dict(showticklabels=False),
    yaxis=dict(tickformat=",.0f"),
    template='simple_white',
    height=400,
    width=1200
)

fig1 = fig1.update_traces(
    hovertemplate='<b>%{x}</b><br>' + 'Reddito mediano: €%{y:,.0f}'
)


Thank you very much, this way the fig1 is no longer duplicated. Solved! :)
